# Como limpio los datos del buffer en c++?

Tags: c++

Tengo el siguiente Ejercicio:
*Hacer una estructura en C++ que registre los datos de cinco personas como: Nombre, apellido, edad, sexo y teléfono.*

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;

struct Persona{
  string nombre;
  string apellido;
  int edad;
  char sexo;
  int telefono;
}per[5];

int main(){

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        cout<<"Nombre: "<<endl;
        cin>>per[i].nombre;
        cout<<"Apellido: "<<endl;
        cin>>per[i].apellido;
        cout<<"Edad: "<<endl;
        cin>>per[i].edad;
        cout<<"Sexo (Ingrese M o F): "<<endl;
        cin>>per[i].sexo;
        cout<<"Telefono: "<<endl;
        cin>>per[i].telefono;


    }



    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Entiendo que aun no escribo la parte del codigo para imprimirlo en pantalla, pero quise probarlo y al ejecutarlo me doy cuenta que me deja llenar los campos de la primera estructura, pero los de las estructuras siguientes me los deja espaciados, como si ya estuvieran llenos por un dato vacio.
Busque este error, y aparentemente quedan datos en el buffer que se almacenan y se toman para completar los datos dentro de la estructura siguiente. Intente utilizar while(getchar()!='\n'); pero tengo el mismo problema.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Cómo puede ser que no tengas ningún error si no incluyes `string`.

Answer (score 0):

En [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) (y en muchos otros lenguajes de programación) las formaciones<sup>1</sup> se indexan desde cero. Por lo que el primer elemento de tu formación de estructuras está en la posición `0`, no en la posición `1`.

Así que tu bucle debería tener este aspecto:

```
for (int i = 0; i != 5; ++i)
{
```

Para hacer más fácil y legible tu código, yo usaría un `for` de rango, lo que te permite ahorrarte pensar en la numeración de los índices y se autoajusta si cambias el tamaño de la formación:

```
for (auto &persona : per)
{
    cout << "Nombre: " << endl;
    cin >> persona.nombre;
    cout << "Apellido: " << endl;
    cin >> persona.apellido;
    cout << "Edad: " << endl;
    cin >> persona.edad;
    cout <<"Sexo (Ingrese M o F): " << endl;
    cin >> persona.sexo;
    cout << "Telefono: " << endl;
    cin >> persona.telefono;
}
```

---

###### <sup>1</sup>También conocidas como *arreglos* o en inglés *arrays*.

Comment: Si, edite ese error de que mi bucle comenzaba en 1, por eso ahora se ve corregido me percate después. No conocía la función del for de rango, veo que se adapta muchísimo mejor a cualquier caso.